# How to kill spring batch job that prevents another instance to run?

Tags: java, spring-batch, windows-server-2012-r2, control-m

I have a spring batch job (launched via Control-M on a windows server) that crashed because of :

`2019-10-23 11:50:44,699 ERROR [main] o.s.b.c.l.s.CommandLineJobRunner [CommandLineJobRunner.java:368] Job Terminated in error: A job execution for this job is already running: JobInstance: id=10, version=0, Job=[stockProjectionJob]`

I have found and killed the java process with the following command :

`wmic process where name="javaw.exe" get commandline,creationdate,processid|find /C "batch"`

But the batch still won't run (same error), what can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all job executions tied to the job instance have a not null end time (tables `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION` and `BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE`)